# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent get x random records from collection where property is null

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Learning `eloquent/laravel`. I have a collection:

```
$regions = Region::with('neighbors')
    ->join('cards', 'cards.id', '=', 'regions.risk_card_id')
    ->get();
```

I have a value or rows:

```
$regionsPerUser = 8;
```

I am doing this to pull random records:

```
$regions = $regions->random($regionsPerUser);
```

But I need to filter this selection where `$regions->user_id` is not null.

Is there a way to filter the random call as part of chaining?

I tried this which does not work:

```
$regions = $regions->whereNotNull('user_id')->random($regionsPerUser);
```

And I am wondering if there is a way to neatly do this in one chained statement as opposed to going down the path of filter / map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just add your conditions to a sql-query:

```
$regions = Region::with('neighbors')
    ->join('cards', 'cards.id', '=', 'regions.risk_card_id')
    ->whereNotNull('user_id')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit($regionsPerUser)
    ->get();
```

If you already have a collection then you can do something like:

```
$regions = $regions
    ->filter(function ($value) {
        return !is_null($value['user_id']);
    })
    ->random($regionsPerUser);
```

Comment: ah no, because this collection has been manipulated post getting it from DB. I am looking to access the collection in memory.